# Qual è l'aggettivo che esprime "non essere affilato"?

Tags: translation, adjectives

Sto cercando di trovare l'aggettivo italiano che traduca il tedesco *"stumpf"*, che significa, nel caso di un coltello specificamente, che **non taglia più**. 
Nel dizionario trovo "spuntato", però questo non è esatto! Nemmeno appuntito funziona.

Voi che aggettivo usereste?

Comment: _stumpf_ significa __anche__ _spuntato_. Comunque una possibilità è _non affilato_.

Comment: Confermo ottuso, oppure quando non taglia piú si dice che "ha perso il filo"

Answer (score 8):

Due possibilità sono **smussato** e **ottuso** (nel senso letterale, anche se lo si usa più in senso figurato).

Comment: Smussato è forse più adatto, mentre ottuso è l'opposto di acuto, che in effetti si adatterebbe al coltello affilato. Tuttavia non so quanti capirebbero cosa significa "il coltello è ottuso".

Answer (score 0):

"Consunto", nel senso che la lama è consumata.

Answer (score -1):

Io direi **spuntato**, anche se di fatto penso non esista un termine preciso in Italiano.